# VB6 .frm File Format property changing for no reason!

Tags: forms, vb6, datetimepicker

We (our company) have been noticing that between check-in's of code to our repository from different users/machines the Format property inside a VB6 form file keep changing, even though we've not changed anything on our PCs.

Before: Format          =   82182147

After:  Format          =   69337091

It's causing a pain with our source code comparison tools picking these up, and it appears to be on date picker controls. The numbers seem to be random as sometimes from the same machine it changes!

All PCs that check-in are on the same locale, same version of vb6.. pretty much same settings as we all have VMs that we develop in (from a standard VM Template).

Anyone know why this changes and how to prevent it? It seems very random!

Comment: I have noticed the same thing, I don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying DateTimePicker Common Control sets its "standard" formats via the lower 6 bits or so of the GWL-STYLE DWORD of its window.  The value for Format stored in the .frm file may well be the entire DWORD of style bits (WS_TABSTOP, WS_VISIBLE, etc.).

So it may be that people are changing other style bitfields, or perhaps even that the IDE is picking up on differences in default values on different machines.  For example some things only exist in later versions of Windows, or perhaps they are different based on whether the user has Luna, Aero, etc. active or not.

Using a "standard VM" makes this less likely though, I admit.