# VB6 stores incrementing number in Format property of DTpicker

Tags: vb6

In Visual Basic 6, for a legacy project I have to maintain, there is a Form with a DTPicker on it.  In the IDE, `Format` is set to `1 - dtpShortDate`.  However, viewing the `.frm` file with a text editor the line is:

```
Format          =   273088513
```

In hex this is `0x10470001` where `0001` part is encoding the `1` - dtpShortDate.

If I wait a few minutes, save the file again, then the line is now:

```
Format          =   274726915
```

i.e. `0x10490001`. Repeating this procedure produces `0x10590001`, `0x107B0001`, etc.

This is really annoying for source control as this value is recalculated most of the times that the form file is saved , so source control is polluted with a bunch of useless changes.

My questions are:

- What is this value and why is it being included?
- Is there a way to prevent it doing this, i.e. so I can make some other change to a form with a DTPicker without generating a useless change for source control?

Comment: Here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6466770/5162073) with a little background information.

Comment: Just a drive-by suggestion with no research: could you store this property as something that doesn't cause this behavior, then set it to short date on form load?

Comment: @BrianMStafford thanks, looks like the same question -- although nobody knew the answer that time either!  Maybe it's even just a uninitialized data bug or something that grabs random value from memory.

Comment: VB6 is rife with useless noise in the FRM (and sometimes FRX) files that mess up source control. We mostly cope with that just by never committing lines we didn't change intentionally. Panful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB6 .frm File Format property changing for no reason!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466770/vb6-frm-file-format-property-changing-for-no-reason)

Comment: @StayOnTarget It doesn't answer my question .. the accepted answer basically says "yeah this happens to me but no idea why either"